# Safari not refreshing 'div' after search call with .load()

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a page divided into two. To the left content, I am loading html content created from database query based on form search inputs. The div is loading fine (I can see it in console.log). But my Safari browser does not load the div. The whole left section appears white. But when I open the web inspector (or move it up and down) the entire div shows!! Is this a refresh issue or a cache issue? Chrome does not throw this issue. Any thoughts?
This is my script.

```
$("#searchBox").on("keyup",function(){
    var search = $(this).val();
    if(search != ""){
      load_data(search);
    } else {
      load_data();
    }
});

function load_data(search){
    $("#leftContent").load("includes/handlers/search-handler.php", {search:search}, "#article");
}
```

the html is:

```
<div class="searchContainer">
<input type="text" id="searchBox" placeholder="start typing">
</div>

<div id="leftContent"></div>
```

Comment: `$("#leftContent").load(` needs to be `$(document).find("#leftContent").load(`

Comment: @AlivetoDie The original code is fine

Comment: Could it be related to timer linked to keyup function? - Deepa

Comment: What is the purpose of the third parameter in the call to _load_ method? It does not seem to comply with the [API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)